# Почему выдает ошибку? sum expected at most 2 arguments, got 3

Tags: python

```
summa = 0
print("Enter eps: ")
eps = float(input())
print("Enter n: ")
n = int(input())
nom = n
denom = 2*n
print(sum(eps, nom, denom))

def sum(eps, nom, denom):
    if fact(nom)/fact(denom) < eps:
        return 0
    else:
        return  (fact(nom) / fact(denom)) + sum(epsilon, nom + 1, denom + 2)

def fact(n):
    if n > 0:
        return n * fact(n-1)
    else:
        return 1
```

Почему выдает ошибку? Функция sum ведь принимает 3 аргумента

Comment: Функции нужно объявлять до их использования: вы вызываете не свою `sum` а одноименную встроенную функцию `sum(iterable, start=0)`, которая на тот момент еще не затенена пользовательской.

Comment: к выше сказанному в фашей функции в строчке sum(epsilon, nom + 1, denom + 2)
переменная epsilon не определена, надо заменить на eps